# Angular 2 Named Outlet: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, named-routing

In a customer management app, I'm trying to have the following:

- **Client List** (Left Side of the Page)
- **Client Details** (Right Side of thePage) dashboard/client/id/
- **Add a Client** (Right Side of the Page).  dashboard/client/new.
- **Edit a Client** (Right Side of the Page). dashboard/client/id/edit

I would like to change the view only on the right side depending what user clicks.

**Router Configuration**

```ts
//imports removed to make this shorter

const clientRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ClientsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ClientListComponent,
        children: [
          { path:'new', 
            component: ClientNewComponent
          },
          { path: ':id', 
            component: ClientDetailComponent,
            resolve: { client: ClientDetailResolver},
            children: [
              { path:'edit',
                outlet: 'section1',
                component: ClientEditComponent,
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(clientRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule ],
  providers: [ClientDetailResolver]
})
export class ClientRouting { }
```

**Client List Component HTML**

```ts
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="row button-wrapper">
    <div class="search-client">
      <i class="search-strong" ></i>
      <input id="searchInput" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="Search client by Name or Phone..." type="text">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-client-details" (click)="onSelectNew()">New Client</button>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div *ngIf="(clients | async)?.length==0">Add a Client</div>
      <div *ngIf="(clients | async)?.length>0" class="vertical-scroll">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr class="muted">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Client ID</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of clients | async | filter:term"
            (click)="onSelect(item)">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Client Detail Component**

```ts
 onSelectEdit(): void {
 this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'section1' : ['edit'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

**Client Detail Component HTML**

```ts
<div class="col-md-7">
 <div>
  <button type="button" class=" btn-client-details"
    (click)="onSelectEdit()">Edit</button>
</div>

<router-outlet name="section1"></router-outlet>

<div *ngIf="client">

//Show all client details for a selected client here {name}{address}etc
</div>
</div>
```

[image: client app]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the path `edit` doesn't exist.

The paths in your module are calculated by concatenating all the paths in the tree (parent + child + child...), which means that you end up with the **relative path** `:id/edit`, or the **absolute path** `/dashboard/client/:id/edit`.

Try with this code:

```ts
// Note. An `id` property must be defined/accessible in your code.

// Relative path syntax
// NB. `ActivatedRoute` must be injected into the `route` property.
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'section1' : [id, 'edit'] } }, { relativeTo: this.route }]);

// Absolute path syntax
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'section1' : ['dashboard', 'client', id, 'edit'] } }]);
```

Comment: This gives me same results. Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id/edit' with id being the corresponding id of a client.

Comment: Oops. I forget that `router.navigate()` doesn't assume paths to be relative by default. I updated my answer with the corrected syntax. I have never tried to combine the `outlets` with the `relativeTo` param. Please confirm whether the relative syntax works once you've had the chance to try it.

Comment: I still didn't have luck with that but now I use this and it  get something:       


        `this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'section1' : ['edit'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });`

However, after I click on "Edit" the form gets rendered on top of the details of the client. I'd like just to have the details view removed and open a form with the details so the user can edit. What is wrong with the router configuration or how can I best approach this pls? See the edited version of my question for references.

Answer (score 0):

It's an angular2 bug: [Secondary child outlet inside empty primary segment does not match](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14662)

What you can try to do is to change the empty path of

```js
path: '',
component: ClientListComponent,
```

to

```js
path: 'whatever',
component: ClientListComponent,
```